# Gwt Front end with python web server

Tags: python, gwt

I am building a web app where I'd like to use GWT for generating the java script that runs in the browser but because I use other python packages (specifically scipy) I would like for the web server to be python (not  a servlet engine). Has anybody done so ? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Ranga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT is a front-end framework. You can use any backend technologies, whether it is Python, PHP, Java, Node.js or any Server-side technologies. There is no limitations on this. I haven't use GWT for quite long now, You have the [request builder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) to fetch data from the server.

Anyway, the simplest solutions that gonna scale for wide range of your devices is to build a REST API on the backend with python, its very simple, you have many simply python technologies like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) that does it in a giffy for you. Build your backend and make it follow REST conventions.

Then, on the level of GWT, it has to have something for fetching data from the webserver. I'll advise to make your data in JSON and then you'll be able to use technologies like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert your JSON serialised string into Java objects on the fly

Comment: gwt generates a file called xxx.nocache.js. I assume this is where all the javascript resides.

Comment: I've forgot a little, but don't touch any generated file by GWT. If you want to use javascript, investigate about JSNI, where you wrap Javascript in Java

Comment: Followup: The combination of Flask and gwt is working nicely. I love all the language features of Java and the util package that it provides as well as the convenience of python for the server.

Answer (score 1):

Pyjamas looks like it was originally a port of GWT to Python:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Pyjamas

This guy doesn't like it though, so you might consider the cons to doing this as well:
http://blog.pyjeon.com/?p=302